# How to recover a site after an xss attack?

Tags: security, web, xss

Recently i was studying about the `XSS` attacks and how devastating they can be on a website.

What surprised me was that, web (*even SO*) is full about ***how to prevent xss attack*** but there is no relevant resource on how to **recover a website, after it has been attacked through xss**.

There are some things which i came across like :

- upload the backup website code back on server
- download the entire site and manually look for any malicious script

but these doesn't sound good enough....i mean, isn't there any other *professionaly active* method to recover the sites once hacked???

Comment: the website itself is not affected in the XSS attack, it the data and security that is compromised, so there should not be any site recovery technique.

Comment: @Furqan : I read that `Cross Site Scripting allows an attacker to embed malicious JavaScript, VBScript, ActiveX, HTML, or Flash into a vulnerable dynamic page to fool the user`, what about these `js` code embedded on the server/website by third parties...how to identify or stop them once idntified??? (quoted text is from => http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/cross-site-scripting/ )

Comment: yep that is pretty much possible with scripting langauages but with the improvements introduced in Web Servers and Serverside languages, these attacks are very much limited now.

Comment: what about `client-side`???...hack is always a hack, be it from server side, be it from client side.....and most of `xss` is `js` based these days (and no...its not *very much limited* ) :)

Comment: for `client-side` attacks, your question `how to recover a website` is out of scope.

Comment: @Furqan : i must have failed to express myself....what i mean is, that, what if `js` based `xss-attack` has been embedded on a site, then how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With XSS the code is not actually modified.  Instead what usually happens are one of two scenarios: reflected and stored XSS.

In reflected XSS, there is some parameter in the request (usually a query string parameter) that gets echoed onto the page without being sanitized.  This could lead to an attacker providing a malicious link to a user, and them clicking and having their session hijacked.

In stored XSS, the attacker finds some way to persist a malicious string (usually stored in a database, in the form of a forum post or website comment) that other users will come across when viewing this site.  That script is then executed in the context of the user that viewed the page, and the attacker could again hijack the session.

To "recover" from reflected XSS - you would want to fix the reflected parameter (do something like output encoding) and invalidate all sessions, making users have to log in again.

To "recover" from reflected XSS - you would want to identify where the malicious code was provided, add sanitization of the input and encoding of the output of that data.  Then clean the database of these malicious values, then invalidate all sessions, forcing users to log back in again.

Answer (score 0):

@Stefan_H got it right. (+1) 
Indeed you only need to recover from stored XSS.

However, what you also need to consider, is that store XSS attack is often just a symptom of the actual illness.

Simply put, to execute such XSS attacks, an attacker must have high-level access to your website/server resources. This means that - besides the malicious XSS code - your site also holds a backdoor shell which allows the attacker that level of access.

And so, in fact, you don't need to recover from XSS but from the backdoor shell. Failing to do so will allow the hacker to re-inject your site, even once the code was sanitized.

Some backdoors exist on a site level, others will affect whole servers. The type of control they provide will vary but - in most cases - they will allow total access to most website resources. This will lead to:

1. XSS and other malware injection
2. Hijacking the site/server for the purpose of DDoS (joining a Botnet)
3. Data theft
4. Eventual defacement

To prevent re-occurring attacks you`ll need to:

1. Use some very early backup (you don't know how long the backdoor was present in your file system)
2. Better yet, use some kind of backdoor detection tool (there are some free ones but few are actually good)
3. Understanding how the shell got there in the 1st place (RFI and password hacks are the two prime suspects)

GL

Comment: By "backdoor" I assume you mean an XSS vulnerability? Please update your answer to clarify.

Comment: Nope. I mean backdoor shells - masked files that provide secondary access point for the hacker. Basically, the second your websites gets hacked, the hacker will try to install such shell, as it will allow long-term control over all website functions. This is how shell may look like: http://www.madirish.net/assets/images/c99-1.png

Comment: I disagree that an attacker needs high level access to execute an XSS attack though - if there's an XSS vulnerability then no particular access level is necessarily required to exploit it. The only time that it would be is if the input was via a page that high level access was needed to view the page, but that would be specific to that particular site.

Comment: Agreed. But I was only referring to stored XSS. Based on my experience these do indicate high probability of in-depth access.