# What hacking risks a site has if it has no input boxes?

Tags: security, xss

I recently posted a question about recovery from XSS attacks on a website, [How to recover a site after an xss attack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759081/how-to-recover-a-site-after-an-xss-attack)...

Doing a bit more digging online, i found that the site is vulnerable to XSS if it allows user to give input or in other words, have any sort of input box in the site (**like** *search box, contact us form, post a feedback etc.* )

Now, what i want to know is that :

- assuming a site has got no input boxes, is it still vulnerable to XSS attack, if *yes*, then how?
- apart from XSS, other hack-attacks a site can face if  it hasn't got any input boxes for user

I know, its a pretty broad question, i just need some heads-up on the topic to google for!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about IT security, and there is a specific SE site for that: security.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig : how can i migrate this question there??? or do i need to repost this question ?

Comment: I’m afraid so. There are a few moderators who could move the question, but I cannot tell you how long it would be until then. If you ask the question there, it’s probably a good idea to link to this one, since you already have some answers.

Comment: Cross posted to: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47658/what-hacking-risks-a-site-has-if-it-has-no-input-boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site is vulnerable to XSS if it receives user input (forms, links, cookies, etc) and returns the content of that data without doing any filtering, or escaping.

- So to your first question, yes, it can be vulnerable, as it might receive user input in the form of links, like:

  ```
  http://sample.com/"><script>alert(/yoursiteisvulnerable/)</script>
  ```

  Which returns a 404 page with this link saying it doesn't exist
- Again, input boxes don't have anything to do with XSS, it is any user-provided input received and used and finally displayed without filtering, so it could be even the `Referer` (spelling mistake is with accordance of the RFC) header being processed and used as input to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Even if there are no input boxes, you can still be vulnerable to Cross-Site-Request-Forgery, if you have buttons or links that lead to actions.